# How do you play sound directly in python?

Tags: python, audio, gtts, python-playsound

I'm trying to find the best way to play a sound in Python without downloading any sound files (eg using temporary files with `tempfile`). This is for a `speak` function using `gTTS`; I've already come up with a solution to save the voice file to a `NamedTemporaryFile` object. The trouble I've had is trying to play it:

```py
from gtts import gTTS
from tempfile import TemporaryFile

def speak(text, lang = 'en'):
    gTTS(text=text, lang=lang).write_to_fp(voice := TemporaryFile())
    #Play voice
    voice.close()
```

I just need something to replace `#Play voice` here, this is the solution I tried:

```py
from gtts import gTTS
from tempfile import NamedTemporaryFile
from playsound import playsound

def speak(text, lang='en'):
    gTTS(text=text, lang=lang).write_to_fp(voice := NamedTemporaryFile())
    playsound(voice.name)
    voice.close()
```

This returns an error:

```
The specified device is not open or is not recognized by MCI.
```

Note: The solution doesn't HAVE to use any of the above modules BESIDES gTTS. As long as the `speak` function can be used repeatedly and without saving any files, it's good enough.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The specified device is not open or is not recognized by MCI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68826091/the-specified-device-is-not-open-or-is-not-recognized-by-mci)

Comment: The code posted in the question works in Python 3.9. OP seems to have an ENV issue in Windows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `pyttsx3` instead of `gtts`. There's no need to save the voice clip, because the voice will directly play at runtime. You can find details here: https://pypi.org/project/pyttsx3/

```py
import pyttsx3
engine = pyttsx3.init()
engine.say("I will speak this text")
engine.runAndWait()
```

Comment: I tried this, but the I received an error when trying the `engine = pyttsx3.init()` line: `DLL load failed while importing win32api: The specified module could not be found.`