# PlaySound keeps giving me errors and not playing sound

Tags: python, mci, python-playsound

I am making an application that requires sound, and when I am trying to play the sound, I keep getting this error:

```
Error 263 for command: open audio1750892060.mp3 The specified device is not open or is not recognized by MCI.
```

And these are the lines of code causing the error:

```
def speak(audio_string):
    tts = gTTS(text=audio_string, lang='en')
    r = random.randint(1, 5000000000)
    audio_file = 'audio' + str(r) + '.mp3'
    tts.save(audio_file)
    playsound.playsound(audio_file)
    print(audio_string)
    os.remove(audio_file)
```

Comment: And you've verified that the mp3s are valid and can be played via other programs, correct?

Comment: @RandomDavis Yes, they work when NOT being played by PlaySound.

Comment: This person had the same issue and it was suggested they try another library for tts - does that fix it for you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58648827/how-do-you-play-sound-directly-in-python Or maybe you could try another module for playing sounds?

Comment: Thanks! I'll give it a look!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a few minutes of messing around, I used the Pygame module to play the sound, and it worked!